# spring config server not refreshing properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a spring boot app that uses the config server to load its properties. The properties exist in the src.main/resources/config directory of the config server project.

When I hit the restful endpoint the properties are loaded fine intially then when I change the properties it still displays the old properties value.  How do I call the refresh endpoint as when I call the URL? Do I call it on config-service or hello-service? Even though from the logs it looks to have mapped them it still throws this 405 error

config-server

```
http://localhost:8889/refresh
```

or hello-service

```
http://localhost:9001/refresh
```

I always get the following

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Oct 20 10:48:03 BST 2015
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported
```

In the config-server at src/main/resources/config I have the following file

hello-service.properties

```
#very-so-much=testing
very-so-much=testing second time
second-time=checking again
```

In my hello-service I have the folloiwng

application.class

```
 @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    CustomerProps customerProps( @Value("${very-so-much}") String exclamations, @Value("${second-time}") String test) {
        CustomerProps p = new CustomerProps();
        //p.setText(exclamations);
        p.setText(test);
        return p;
    }
```

Controller class

```
//    @Value("${very-so-much}")
//    private String prop;
//    
//    @Value("${second-time}")
//    private String anotheerProp;

    @Autowired
    public GreetingController(CustomerRepository repository, GridFsTemplate gridFileSystem, CustomerProps props) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.fs = gridFileSystem;
        this.props = props;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        name = props.getText();
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
```

The start up logs for config-server show the endpoints below

```
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.616  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/health],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(java.security.Principal)
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.617  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/restart],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.context.restart.RestartMvcEndpoint.invoke()
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.618  INFO 13120 --- [           main] 
o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint.value(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.618  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env/reset],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint.reset()
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.619  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mappings],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.619  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/beans],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.620  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.620  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.620  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/autoconfig],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.620  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/info],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.626  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/refresh],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.628  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.629  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.629  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/configprops],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.697  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.710  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'refreshEndpoint' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.712  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'restartEndpoint' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.712  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'configurationPropertiesRebinder' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.714  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'refreshScope' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.715  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'environmentManager' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.721  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'environmentManager': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager]
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.751  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'restartEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.restart:name=restartEndpoint,type=RestartEndpoint]
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.760  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'refreshScope': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh:name=refreshScope,type=RefreshScope]
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.768  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinder': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties:name=configurationPropertiesRebinder,type=ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder]
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.787  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'refreshEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config:name=refreshEndpoint,type=RefreshEndpoint]
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.791  INFO 13120 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.897  INFO 13120 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8889 (http)
    2015-10-20 10:25:49.898  INFO 13120 --- [           main] doge.ConfigurationServerApplication      : Started ConfigurationServerApplication in 4.485 seconds (JVM running for 5.233)
    2015
```

And my hello-service logs show below

```
2015-10-20 10:36:24.822  INFO 11564 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2eea88a1: startup date [Tue Oct 20 10:36:21 BST 2015]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@400cff1a
2015-10-20 10:36:24.886  INFO 11564 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/customer],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> hello.GreetingController.add(hello.Customer)
2015-10-20 10:36:24.887  INFO 11564 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/customer/add],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public hello.Customer hello.GreetingController.insertCustomer(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2015-10-20 10:36:24.887  INFO 11564 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/customer/greeting],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public hello.Greeting hello.GreetingController.greeting(java.lang.String)
2015-10-20 10:36:24.887  INFO 11564 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/customer/{lastName}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> hello.GreetingController.readCustomer(java.lang.String)
2015-10-20 10:36:24.889  INFO 11564 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2015-10-20 10:36:24.889  INFO 11564 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[text/html],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2015-10-20 10:36:24.914  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-10-20 10:36:24.914  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-10-20 10:36:24.947  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-10-20 10:36:25.333  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/info],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-10-20 10:36:25.333  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/trace],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-10-20 10:36:25.334  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/restart],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.context.restart.RestartMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2015-10-20 10:36:25.334  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/health],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(java.security.Principal)
2015-10-20 10:36:25.334  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/pause],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2015-10-20 10:36:25.335  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2015-10-20 10:36:25.335  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-10-20 10:36:25.335  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/refresh],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2015-10-20 10:36:25.336  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/resume],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2015-10-20 10:36:25.336  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/dump],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-10-20 10:36:25.336  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/autoconfig],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-10-20 10:36:25.337  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint.value(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2015-10-20 10:36:25.337  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env/reset],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint.reset()
2015-10-20 10:36:25.338  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2015-10-20 10:36:25.338  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-10-20 10:36:25.338  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mappings],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-10-20 10:36:25.338  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/beans],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-10-20 10:36:25.338  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/configprops],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-10-20 10:36:25.373  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2015-10-20 10:36:25.380  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'refreshEndpoint' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2015-10-20 10:36:25.380  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'restartEndpoint' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2015-10-20 10:36:25.381  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'configurationPropertiesRebinder' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2015-10-20 10:36:25.381  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'refreshScope' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2015-10-20 10:36:25.382  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'environmentManager' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2015-10-20 10:36:25.384  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'environmentManager': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager]
2015-10-20 10:36:25.398  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'restartEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.restart:name=restartEndpoint,type=RestartEndpoint]
2015-10-20 10:36:25.405  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'refreshScope': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh:name=refreshScope,type=RefreshScope]
2015-10-20 10:36:25.411  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinder': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties:name=configurationPropertiesRebinder,type=ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder]
2015-10-20 10:36:25.425  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'refreshEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config:name=refreshEndpoint,type=RefreshEndpoint]
2015-10-20 10:36:25.431  INFO 11564 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2015-10-20 10:36:25.529  INFO 11564 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 9001 (http)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As this is a POST request and thus running a curl command as below

```
curl -d {} http://localhost:9001/refresh
```

did refresh my properties.

Answer (score 2):

For Spring 2

1. Url - `http://localhost:<portNo>/actuator/refresh`
2. Request Method Type - `POST`